# Does allowing access to a bucket automatically imply access to everything inside?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

For a policy to allow access to a bucket *and everything inside it*, does the 'Any' box next to object need to be checked (or does simply allowing access to a bucket imply access to its contents)?

[image]

There are two reasons I ask i) so that the policy has access to the objects inside the bucket, but also ii) to confirm that checking the 'Any' box *doesn't* give access to objects *outside* the specified bucket(s) (it could be bad if it did and that wasn't realised) - I assume it probably doesn't but best to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, access to a bucket (as indicated by a policy resource like `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket`) does not provide any API access to the objects within that bucket. To access the objects, you would need to allow API actions against an object resource like `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*`.

The IAM dialog you've shown is a convenience that helps you to create a JSON policy. At any time, you can click the JSON tab to see the equivalent JSON policy.

The dialog has 4 resource types: accesspoint, bucket, job, object. They are *independent* of one another. Selecting a specific S3 bucket under the 'bucket' section does *not* have any impact on the 'object' section.

So, if you indicate `mybucket` under bucket and `Any` under object, your policy will contain something like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::*/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    ]
}
```

Note specifically, that this allows all S3 actions (`s3:*`) against both the bucket (`arn:aws:s3:::mybucket`) and *all* the objects in *all* the buckets (`arn:aws:s3:::*/*`).

If you want to allow actions against the `mybucket` bucket and against all of the objects in `mybucket`, then indicate `mybucket` under bucket, deselect 'Any' under object, and indicate `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*` under object. Your JSON policy will now look like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    ]
}
```